# How to set Android wallpaper?

Tags: android, delphi

*Can anyone tell me how to programmatically set the Wallpaper on Android desktop in Delphi XE5-8?*
Thanks.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1FKFpGV

Comment: See [Code Snippet To Set The Device Wallpaper In Delphi XE7 Firemonkey On Android](http://www.fmxexpress.com/code-snippet-to-set-the-device-wallpaper-in-delphi-xe7-firemonkey-on-android/).

Answer (score 1):

Copy of the link by @LURD and @FreeConsulting

Here's a way to Set the wallpaper.don't know how right or wrong it is).

Live wallpaper is not to much different, so this is a starting point

> 1. Use Java2op to generate the delphi bridge files of all the wallpaper classes.
> 2. New Fmx poject
> 3. Add the units to your uses clause along with:
> 4. place the following on the form:
>      Button1: TButton;
>      Image1: TImageViewer;
> 5. Load an image into Image1 in design time. and set Button1 onclick to below.

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  FWallpaperManager: JWallpaperManager;
  Factoryoptions: JBitmapFactory_Options;
  AScreenSize: TPoint;
  WidthOfScreen, HeightOfScreen: Integer;
  FFileToOpen: string;
begin
  {Create a filename to save the image to}
  FFiletoopen:= System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Thefile.jpg');
  {Save the image}
  Image1.Bitmap.SaveToFile(FFileToOpen);
  {Create JBitmap options }
  Factoryoptions:= TJBitmapFactory_Options.Create;
  {Read up on these in the android API}
  Factoryoptions.inJustDecodeBounds:= True;
  Factoryoptions.inPreferQualityOverSpeed:= True;
  Factoryoptions.inJustDecodeBounds:= False;
  {Get the wallpaper manager instance}
  FWallpaperManager:= TJWallpaperManager.Wrap((SharedActivityContext.GetSystemService
               (TJContext.JavaClass.WALLPAPER_SERVICE) as  ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  {Load the image we saved}
  TheBitmaptoShow:= TJBitmapfactory.JavaClass.DecodeFile(StringToJString(FFiletoopen), FactoryOptions);
  {Only change the wallpaper if the Bitmap loads}
  if TheBitmaptoShow <> nil then begin
    {Set the Wallpaper}
    FWallpaperManager.SetBitmap(TheBitmaptoShow);        
  end;
end;
```